# How to get the status of a checkbox in Android Studio.

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to set message to the state of the checkbox but it keeps giving errors. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
   if (null == savedInstanceState) {
        if (PluginBundleManager.isBundleValid(localeBundle)) {
            final String message =
                    localeBundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
            ((CheckBox) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(message);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    //User cancelled
    if (isCanceled()) {
        super.finish();
        return;
    }

    //Sanity check
    final Boolean message = ((CheckBox) findViewById(android.R.id.text1).isEnabled());
    if (message == true) {
        super.finish();
        return;
    }

    final Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
```

Comment: post the error ie logcat/stacktrace report you are getting

Comment: **android.R.id.text1** ? please post your xml and logcat

Comment: final Boolean message = ((CheckBox) findViewById(android.R.id.text1).isEnabled());

This isn't valid. You are casting a bool to CheckBox.
Perhaps this was just a typo, but if that is your actual code, it won't build.

Should look like this: final Boolean message = ((CheckBox) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).isEnabled();

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a paranthesis
In this line :

```
final Boolean message = ((CheckBox) findViewById(android.R.id.text1).isEnabled());
```

change it to

```
final Boolean message = ((CheckBox) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).isEnabled();
```

Comment: That is still incorrect. You have an extra parenthesis on the end. Should be this: final Boolean message = ((CheckBox) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).isEnabled();